# Angular 8, after deployment on server, refresh/reload show 404 page not found

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am facing issue, 404 page not found. after the use HashLocationStrategy, .htaccess, webcong but issue still appearing.
The mentioned process not working

Using software

- Front End - Angular 8
- Back End - Php

app.module.ts

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from "@angular/common";
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mod_rewrite`. Good way to put it is in `.htaccess`. However, to get more help you need to improve your question... a lot!

Comment: I used below code in in htaccess

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: How is `web.config` relevant to your question? You don't mention anything about server-side technologies. You really need to start with some tutorial; it covers how to avoid 404, depending on the stack. Voting to close